# Centos 7 - where is jfx library for openjdk8?

Tags: linux, centos, java

I have centos 7.1. And I installed openjdk8 and openjdk-devel8. However, when I tried to compile in netbeans my jfx application I get `package javafx.* does not exist`. After some investigation I see that there is no jfxrt.jar in jdk. Besides

```
[root@localhost ext]# yum provides jfxrt.jar
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.astpage.ru
 * epel: epel.besthosting.ua
 * extras: mirror.astpage.ru
 * nux-dextop: mirror.li.nux.ro
 * updates: mirror.astpage.ru
adobe-linux-x86_64/filelists             |  619 B  00:00:00     
base/7/x86_64/filelists_db               | 6.0 MB  00:00:01     
epel/x86_64/filelists_db                 | 6.3 MB  00:00:01     
extras/7/x86_64/filelists_db             |  87 kB  00:00:00     
nux-dextop/x86_64/filelists_db           | 2.3 MB  00:00:02     
updates/7/x86_64/filelists_db            | 836 kB  00:00:00     
No matches found
[root@localhost ext]#
```

So my question - how to add jfx library to openjdk 8 on centos 7?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547362/javafx-and-openjdk

Answer (score 2):

OpenJDK 8 for CentOS doesn't have JavaFX included by default...
You can do one of the following:

**Switch to Oracle JDK:**
1. remove all open jdks & jre's until when you type "java" in a shell it doesn't recognize
2. download from oracle the .rpm and install it via `yum localinstall`

or

**Manually copy the JavaFX jars from another computer that has them**
I never tested this myself, but some people mentioned it might work

or

**Make a custom build of OpenJDK and include JavaFX**

Hoping this was helpful...

Comment: Another possibility is [ZuluFX](https://www.azul.com/downloads/zulu/zulufx/).

Answer (score 1):

download jdk-8u91-linux-x64.tar.gz archive of oracle jdk from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html, unpack and set PATH and JAVA_HOME to it.
Just keep in mind that you have to watch security updates on your own.